# Trying to install grequests on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip, grequests

When I try to install grequests on Ubuntu with pip:

```
sudo pip install grequests
```

I get this error, but my gcc seems fine:

```
In file included from gevent/core.c:253:0:

gevent/libevent.h:9:19: fatal error: event.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install libevent, which on Ubuntu can be done with:

```
apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Alternatively, to install gevent and all it's dependencies automatically:

```
apt-get install python-gevent
```

Comment: Should be `apt-get install python-gevent` instead `apt-get intall python-gevent`. Small typo :)

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get install libevent-dev`

Answer (score 2):

`grequests` depends on the Python module `gevent`, and `pip` will pull that in for you automatically.

`gevent` depends on the C library `libevent`, and there's no way `pip` can take care of that for you. So, you need to install it manually, e.g., using your distro's package manager.

(Alternatively, `gevent` 1.0 and later no longer rely on `libevent`, or any other external dependencies. But, as of 25 Sep 2013, 1.0 isn't out yet…)

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same error. Following commands helped me:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev libssl-dev python3-dev
```

Now try to install `grequests` again by following command:

- **Python 2**

  ```
   $ pip install grequests
  ```
- **Python 3.x**

  ```
   $ pip3 install grequests
  ```

If these commands doesn't help, then you can use the following commands:

- **Python 2**

  ```
   $ sudo apt install python-pip
   $ pip install wheel
  ```
- **Python 3.x**

  ```
   $ sudo apt install python3-pip
   $ pip3 install wheel
  ```

**OR**

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv python3-wheel -y
```

Now retry to install `grequests`. Hope the installation will work properly now.